# How to remove elements in an arraylist start from an indicated index

Tags: java, arraylist, queue, element

As the picture shown, after one time run a method, i want remove the old items, and prepared for next time calculation, but i wondering how to remove elements in an arraylist start from an indicated index, like a queue, obey FIFO algorithm?
[image: q1]

Comment: @Katona :) i go to read that, hopes can find a solution

Comment: in the meantime I managed to fabricate a short answer as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [List#subList(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

```
List<Integer> list =  ...
list = list.subList(10, list.size()); // creates a new list from the old starting from the 10th element
```

or, since `subList` creates a view on which every modification affects the original list, this may be even better:

```
List<Integer> list = ...
list.subList(0, 10).clear(); // clears the first 10 elements of list
```

Comment: When i use "purchase=(ArrayList<Integer>) purchase.subList(index,purchase.size());" gives me an exception error..java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.RandomAccessSubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: @atom2ueki do not use `ArrayList` as the type of the variable, use `List` as I did with `list` in my answer

Comment: yap,that's return me an correct result, :),but what's different between list and arraylist here?

Comment: @atom2ueki `List` is an _interface_ which defines the behaviour of a list without saying anything of the details. `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List` which happens the store the elements in an array (this is a detail, which you are not facing it when you use the interface). Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/LinkedList.html) method for this.

Let's assume you want to remove elements with indices from 20 to 30 of an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> list = ...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // 30 - 20 = 10
  list.remove(20);
}
```

Once the first element at index `20` is removed element `21` moves to index `20`. So you have to delete 10 times the element at index `20` to remove the next 10 elements.

Comment: your method seems only remove the 20th element

Comment: Have you read the sentence bellow the code? There are no "holes" within an array list. If you remove the element with index 20 the next element will move to this index.

Comment: I think it would be easier to unterstand, if you loop backwards from 30 to 20. And use `list.remove(i)`

Comment: @micha  i tried tis method, but seems that loop is not started, the logic is correct, it only remove one element 20

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing no high performance application it is bad style to store so much semantics in an index variable.

A better approach would be the use of a map.

E. g. `Map<Item, Integer> itemStock` and `Map<Item, Double> prices`. You then also wouldn't have any problems with the remove operation.

Comment: but if using map,i still need an identifier for each map,does it the same of list here? sorry, i'm not fully get what you mean

Comment: Maps don't work with indices, they work with Keys. Keys are objects, that's what one would do in OOP, it's easier to maintain the code with identifiers than maintaining codes where integers have a meaning beyond just being a number. You should write an `Item` class or sth. like that and use it as key to a map.